# Invariant Violation: View config not found for name option (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use this library https://github.com/country-regions/react-country-region-selector for my react native application.

The example code is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

// note that you can also export the source data via CountryRegionData. It's in a deliberately concise format to
// keep file size down
import {
  CountryDropdown,
  RegionDropdown,
  CountryRegionData
} from "react-country-region-selector";

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { country: "", region: "" };
  }

  selectCountry(val) {
    this.setState({ country: val });
  }

  selectRegion(val) {
    this.setState({ region: val });
  }

  render() {
    const { country, region } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <CountryDropdown
          value={country}
          onChange={val => this.selectCountry(val)}
        />
        <RegionDropdown
          country={country}
          value={region}
          onChange={val => this.selectRegion(val)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

I changed the `divs` in the render method into `View`, which has left me with the current error: Invariant Violation: View config not found for name option.

I'm not sure if this is because the library is intended for React as opposed to React-Native or if there is something else going on that I'm unaware of.

Comment: this library is using `option` and `select` under the hood, which are not available in react-native

Comment: dang, ok thanks for the response!

Comment: its a really simple library, so you could probably replace those with react-native `Picker` fairly easily

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I'm not sure how to do that, I don't understand how you were able to determine that `option` and `select` were being used under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because this library renders HTML, which is not available in `react-native`. You can confirm this by going to `node_modules/react-country-region-selector/src` to see the source code.

However, the `Picker` component in `react-native` has a very similar API, so you could easily remake this to be compatible. Note that you should not edit files in your `node_modules` as they will be corrected any time you run yarn / npm. Instead, you should create your own local version of this module.

It's really just a matter of replacing `select` with `Picker` and `option` with `Picker.Item` and changing the `onChange` handlers to work with the `Picker` instead of expecting a DOM event.

[You can learn more about the Picker API here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker)

Comment: I appreciate your comment, I'm not clear how to replace select and option when neither of those keywords are in the example code?

Comment: You have to use the modules source code, look at the files in the directory `node_modules/react-country-region-selector/src` and you'll see what I mean